# How to create a windows kernel driver/service in C#?

Tags: c#, service, kernel

I've developed an audio device which records voice and response using AI technology and it works well. Now I am going to use this device with my computer and to communicate and control my device, I need to program in kernel mode. How can I create a windows kernel driver/service in C#?

I've asked to many people but they don't know well about kernel.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think you can't. You'll probably need C/C++, I guess.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/ and taken from the portable sub article "Code in C (no assembly language)." C++ may be ok but comes with risks. But read yourself.

Comment: Writing kernel level code requires pretty much the opposite of what you get with a managed environment like .NET. you need control of every page of memory you work with, what pages are resident , which ones are paged out. As @ralf mentioned, many kernel developers look at C++ and think that is doesn't provide the control/ management you need when working with a kernel-level driver